# If current is charge flow through a point then isn't the surface current always zero?

Tags: electric-current, calculus

Current is defined as the rate of flow of charge through a point. Now say we've got a surface charge density $\sigma$ which moves around on a surface.

According to the above definition the current anywhere on the surface should be zero because the amount of charge flowing across a **point** is zero since a point has no area.

If I'm correct why do texts talk about current on a surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current is defined as the rate of flow of charge, and its definition does not specify the surface or curve across which the flow is measured. In 3D situations, the flow is through a given surface, which may also be deforming and in motion with respect to a reference frame. In 2D situations, which are approximations to 3D situations, the flow is through a curve. In 1D situations, another approximation, the flow is through a point. When we divide (by a limit procedure) the current by the area of the surface, or the length of the curve, we have a current *density*, with units current/length$^2$ or current/length; the 1D case is degenerate, current/length$^0$.

Let me quote Maxwell himself ([*A Treatise on Electricity and Magnetism* I](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonelectr01maxwrich), 1881, §12):

> Physical vector quantities may be divided into two classes,
> in one of which the quantity is defined with reference to a line,
> while in the other the quantity is defined with reference to an
> area. [...]
>
> In electrical science, electromotive and magnetic intensity
> belong to the first class, being defined with reference to lines.
> When we wish to indicate this fact, we may refer to them as
> Intensities.
>
> On the other hand, electric and magnetic induction, and electric
> currents, belong to the second class, being defined with reference
> to areas. When we wish to indicate this fact, we shall refer to them
> as Fluxes.

If you check other texts such as Kovetz's *Electromagnetic Theory* or Jackson's *Classical Electrodynamics* you'll find similar definitions.

In your case you're considering a 2D situation. Then current is defined with respect to a (1D) curve, not an area nor a point.